# object.ToString() behavior when object is null

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I have following c# code that written in 2.0 framework

```
SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Connection String");
mySqlConnection.Open();
SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT OutputType FROM Reports WHERE ReportID = 'NEWREP'";

return mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

When there is no record for the sql query, ExecuteScalar will return null object and can able to convert the null object into string by ToString().

There were no exceptions thrown.

But when the same code against .Net 4.0 , throws exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

either i can able to use

```
return mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

or

```
return (string)mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

to handle the exception in 4.0

But i wants to know why 2.0 not thrown the exception? Any clue of this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```ExecuteScalar will return null object and can able to convert the null object into string by ToString()``` - this cannot be, recheck pls 2.0 solution, seems it returned something

Comment: Yeah, I'm not buying that either.  That would be a breaking change.

Comment: It cannot be working on .net2.0 recheck, it's impossible as the other said. For solution you can use inline null checks like `return mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString() ?? "";`

Comment: Note that `null != DBNull.Value` - perhaps you are mixing these two up as you are able to call `ToString` on `DBNull.Value` but not on `null`?

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteScalar` returns null if no matching data found.

`object.ToString()` throws `NullReferenceException` if the `object` is `null`. This is irrespective of dot net framework version. I suspect your observations with framework 2.0 are incorrect.

To handle nulls, there are multiple ways. You have already stated two of them.

```
return Convert.ToString(mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

**Edit for your comment:**

> Both 4.0 code and 2.0 pointing to same SQL DB with same code. I have only exe file (2.0 version) so not able to debug for what value it returns. But sure there is no exception thrown

This is not about `ToString()` only and this is not about C# or .NET. Note that the method is being called on `object`. Full call statement is `object.ToString()`. If `object` is `null`, it is obvious that it's `ToString()` member could not be accessed and hence the exception. Any member access on `null` instance will result in same exception in any version for most of the programming languages those do not create implicit instances.

Comment: Both 4.0 code and 2.0 pointing to same SQL DB with same code. I have only exe file (2.0 version) so not able to debug for what value it returns. But sure there is no exception thrown